# How do I test my devise user model validations using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I can find recommendations for testing devise user controllers and views in RSpec.  I've also seen suggestions that the devise gem code is already tested so it's not useful to spend a lot of time reinventing the wheel.

However, my user model has other fields that I need validated when the user signs up.  I'm using standard `validates...` statements in the user.rb model.  For example:

```
validates_presence_of     :nickname
```

I'm trying to use simple validation testing in my user_spec.rb, but when I try to create the user like this:

```
record = Factory.create(:user)
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `encode!' for "Confirmation":String
```

The `encode!` method is not coming from my code, it must be one of the gems that devise is using, but I haven't been able to find it, yet.

I've tried creating the user using User.new and Factory Girl.  I get the same error either way.  This spec was passing until I did an update of all my gems.  Unfortunately I didn't keep a note of everything that got updated at the time.  I've tried rolling devise back to previous versions but still get the same error.

Rails 3, RSpec2

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be fine, may be, my testing code helps you out:

user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before :each do
    @user = Factory.build(:user)
  end

  it "should not be valid without a first_name" do
    @user.first_name = nil
    @user.should_not be_valid
  end

end
```

user.rb (Model)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :first_name

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :lockable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :login, :first_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessor :login

  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :validatable

  protected

  def password_required?
    !persisted? || password.present? || password_confirmation.present?
  end



end
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm thinking it may be what I'm including (or missing) when I create the user.  What does your Factory definition for :user look like?  Mine is:
`Factory.define :user, :class => User do |f| 
  f.id 327
  f.email 'shadow@example.com'
  f.password 'shadow33'
  f.password_confirmation 'shadow33'
  f.nickname 'shadow'
end`

Comment: Your example led me to the culprit...  the difference between `Factory.create(:user)` and `Factory.build(:user)`.  Thanks for the help!